# ios custom takePicture button

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I want my custom button to take a picture using `UIImagePickerController` and to save it in my device.

I can save the picture in the device using the default camera controls, although when i turn them off and start using my custom button it doesn't do the job.

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    [picker takePicture];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(chosenImage, nil, nil, nil);

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

`didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is being called but the picture isn't being saved.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar and used this tutorial to get be started. Have a look.

http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=821